# Is there any way to combine artificial intelligence/expert system with vb.net programs?

Tags: vb.net, prolog, artificial-intelligence, swi-prolog, expert-system

I have recently learnt SWI-Prolog, an expert system/artificial intelligence designer that uses declarative programming.
I wish to combine it with existing vb.net 2010 console and windows forms programs to make a basic user friendly expert system.

How do I go about linking the two of them to get this functionality?

Or is there a way to do logic processing in vb.net?

Thanks in advance,
Vishwas

Comment: As you noted with my incorrect suggest, [C# to SWI-Prolog by Uwe Lesta](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx) did not work with VB .NET. The next option is to recreate Prolog with source code in .Net.

Comment: Here are few worth a look: [C# Prolog](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-prolog/), [Prolog .NET](https://prolog.codeplex.com/) or [P#](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/research/Psharp/). I looked at these several years ago and found them lacking for what I needed, ([immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)), and have not looked at them in any detail since, however they may suit your needs. While the task you seek is not as easy as I would have hoped, it is doable.